# Missing reaction when evaluating string return to string

Tags: javascript, fetch

If som condition is meet my python backend returns :"GAME OVER"

I would like to react to that i my JavaScript frontend, but it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
    function pickCardFromCards(){
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/pickCardFromCards/'+player)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(data => {
            data = data.replace('"', '');
            data = data.replace('"', ''); //Do it twice.
            console.log(typeof(data));
            console.log(data);
            document.getElementById("cards").innerHTML = data;
            if (data=="GAME OVER"){
                console.log('GAME OVER!');
            }
        });
    }
```

In the console I get this:

```
string
GAME OVER
```

But I would expect

```
string
GAME OVER
GAME OVER!
```

Why is that?

BR Kresten

Comment: You only have 2 `console.log()` so why are you expecting 3 lines of output? You say it prints `GAME OVER` but there is no place in your code where you log that string.

Comment: sorry, please see edit

Comment: Could it be that there are spaces after `GAME OVER` ? If you try printing `data.length`, that should show `9`. If not, then there is something in it that does not show when printed (e.g. spaces, tabs, strange unicode stuff).

Comment: I get 10, but backend is for sure returning 'GAME OVER', with only 9 characters. Where does the last come from ?